# How to calculate voltage between AC phases with different angles?

Tags: voltage, ac, three-phase, homework

I am trying to understand some fundamentals about AC three phase wave forms, in this case is related to how to get the voltages between phases in real environment that as we know they have different angles.

let's say thay I have this situation:

[image: aceg]

As I know if the ideal 3 phases have equal 120° from each other we can apply eg.

**VLL=√3 * VLN**

In my case the 3 phases have different voltages and different angles.

Eg.

- L1= 130V
- L2= 120V
- Angle between L1 & L2 110°

I still don't know to get Vab and/or how to spread out the know formula VLL=√3 *VLN

Comment: johnnytolengo - Welcome :-) For assignment / test / homework-type questions like this, we need to see your own work *first*. That is currently missing, so your question has been "[closed](/help/closed-questions)". However as explained in that link, it will automatically be put in a queue to consider re-opening it, if within 5 days you [Edit] your question, add your own analysis / calculations & your best solution attempt so far (which parts of the question *can* you attempt?) and make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck. Thanks.

Comment: One way of solving the problem would be to work out the XY coordinates of Va and Vb and then find the distance between them using \$ V_{ab} = \sqrt{ (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 } \$. Try it and show your calculations.

Comment: You can't "spread out the know formula VLL=√3 *VLN" if the load is unbalanced. I've given you a big clue. Do you know how to get sines and cosines of angles? Can you work out the distance from the tip of one to the other using coordinate geometry?

Comment: Look at comment from the junction (*Transistor*) Vector Vab = Vector Va - Vector Vb.  Vector subtraction.  And you have edited the question, but this is still homework without an attempt.  Ignore VLL=√3 *VLN because components are unbalanced.  That only works if all are the same.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Neutral point is the star center. Va,Vb,Vc are phase voltages to neutral, Vab is the phase to phase (line) voltage L1 to L2. Using a Pitagora you can calculate the  phase to phase (line) voltage as:

$$V_{line}=\sqrt{3}\cdot V_{phase}$$

Comment: So if I want to get the voltage between L1 and L2 it should be Vab=(√Va^2+Va^2 ) * Va ? using plain pitagora : c=√a2+b2=120^2+120^2≈169.70563  in lost with this simple equation

Comment: if I well understand, if both lines have different voltages the math must be a little different